# Bootstrap Mobile Menu Resizing to Desktop

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, window-resize

I've built a custom mobile menu for my HTML page. This mobile menu sits at the bottom of the content and is hidden, until selected using the following:-

```
<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse"  aria-expanded="false" id="mobile-navigation-toggle">
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
</button>
```

This is the standard hamburger menu icon that appears with Bootstrap on mobile. The custom mobile menu looks like this:-

```
<div id="menu" class="nav-collapse">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I then have a JS function that opens and closes this menu as I want it too, and this works fine.

```
$("#mobile-navigation-toggle").click(function() {
var expanded = $(this).attr('aria-expanded');

if(expanded == "true") {
    $(this).attr('aria-expanded','false');
    $("#main").animate({marginLeft:'0px'},'slow');   
}
else {
    $(this).attr('aria-expanded','true');
    $("#main").animate({marginLeft:'500px'},'slow');   
} 
});
```

I have a problem though when re-sizing from mobile to desktop - I want this mobile menu (which may or may not be expanded at the time), to slide shut and the main content be slid back. The mobile menu pushes in from the left.

I've written this, which works fine, but I feel like it might be quite hacky.

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    var width = $(window).width();
    console.log(width);

    <!-- Is there a better way of doing this? -->
    if(width >= 750) {
        $("#mobile-navigation-toggle").attr('aria-expanded','false');
        $("#main").animate({marginLeft:'0px'},'slow');  
    }
    <!-- End Is there a better way of doing this? -->
});
```

Is there a better way to test whether the bootstrap desktop/mobile menu is displaying than checking a width of 750 and sliding the menu shut?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you post a fiddle (full and works) so it will be easier for us to answer?

Comment: Is it acceptable to post a link the HTML page on my own site? Not sure how to include the bootstrap contents on JsFiddle.

Comment: Hi, here is the link to the page - http://www.mike-upjohn.co.uk/projects/new-site/

If you narrow the screen size, you should see the hamburger menu at the top left of the page. Open the menu and then re-size the window to desktop, and you'll see I've set it to slide shut the mobile menu. Is there a better way of doing it than via the code above, testing the width for greater than or less than 750 pixels?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`@media query`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp) to detect the window width.

Just add to your css:

```
#main {
   transition:all .3s ease;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 480px) {
   #main {
       margin:0 !important;
   }
}
```

Also, you need to change the `animate` function in `$("#main").animate({marginLeft:'0px'},'slow');` to `css` - the css `transition` will take care about the animation.

Notice that you have couple of `#main` in tour site. You should to fix this.

Comment: Thanks, I will try this tonight and mark it as an answer if this works. Thanks for your support! I'm a newbie to bootstrap, but it has thus far made life a lot easier.